# second page is not updating while using tr dir-paginate

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using onaftersave() function to save the table data. In dir-paginate i am using ng-repeat to read the table row values. I kept itemsperpage is 5. obviously  6th row will  be display in second Page. When I try to edit the second page row values it is not updating the second page rows. How to resolve it?

```
<form editable-form name="tableform1" oncancel="cancel()" onaftersave="saveTable(Manage_Role.Description)">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="panel panel-default panel-table">

                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col col-xs-6">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col col-xs-6 text-right">
                                                        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-create" title="Add New Role">Add New Role</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-body scrollbar">

                                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th style="width: 25%" align="center">
                                                                <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='RoleName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort" title="Name">Name</a>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th style="width: 35%">
                                                                <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='Description'; reverseSort = !reverseSort" title="Description">Description</a>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th style="width: 30% " align="center">
                                                                <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='IsActive'; reverseSort = !reverseSort" title="IsActive?">IsActive?</a>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th style="width: 10% " align="center"><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='IsActive';
                                                             reverseSort = !reverseSort" title="Assign">Assign</a></th>
                                                            <th style="width: 1%" align="center" ng-show="false">DirtyFlag</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>

                                                    <tbody>

                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input type="text" id="RoleNameID" ng-model="Manage_Role1.RoleName" placeholder="search" class="searchbox" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);"
                                                                />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input type="text" id="DescriptionID" ng-model="Manage_Role1.Description" placeholder="search" class="searchbox" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);"
                                                                />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <select name="DropFilter" ng-model="Manage_Role1.IsActive" class="searchbox">
                                                                            <option value="">All</option>
                                                                             <option value=false>False</option>
                                                                              <option value=true>True</option>  
                                                                </select>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <!--<td></td>-->

                                                        </tr>

                                                        <tr dir-paginate="Manage_Role in Manage_Roleser  | itemsPerPage:5 | filter:DropFilter | filter:Manage_Role1 | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort "
                                                            ng-class-odd="'odd'">
                                                            <td ng-click="tableform1.$show()">
                                                                <span e-ng-change="applyHighlight($data,$index)" editable-text="Manage_Role.RoleName" ng-attr-title="{{Manage_Role.RoleName}}"
                                                                    e-form="rowform" ng-click="rowform.$show()">
                                                                    {{ Manage_Role.RoleName | uppercase }}
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td ng-click="tableform1.$show()">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <span e-ng-change="applyHighlight($data,$index)" editable-text="Manage_Role.Description" e-form="rowform" ng-attr-title="{{Manage_Role.Description}}"
                                                                        ng-click="rowform.$show()">
                                                                        {{ Manage_Role.Description || 'empty' }}
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td ng-click="tableform1.$show()" align="center">
                                                                <span e-ng-change="applyHighlight($data,$index)" ng-checked="Manage_Role.IsActive" editable-checkbox="Manage_Role.IsActive"
                                                                    e-form="rowform" ng-click="applyHighlight($data,$index);tableform.$show()">
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Manage_Role.IsActive" width="20" ng-attr-title="{{Manage_Role.IsActive}}" />
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td align="center">
                                                                <input type="image" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="Rolepopupclick(Manage_Role._id,Manage_Role.RoleName)" title="Assign UI"
                                                                    data-target="#Div1" src="App_Themes/Images/AssignUser.png"
                                                                    alt="Submit" width="28" height="28" />
                                                            </td>

                                                            <td ng-show="false">
                                                                <input type="text" ng-model="Manage_Role.DirtyFlag" ng-show="false" />
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                            </div>

                                            </table>


                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-footer">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col col-xs-8">
                                                    <dir-pagination-controls max-size="5" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true">
                                                    </dir-pagination-controls>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col col-xs-4">
                                                    <div class="btn-form" ng-show="tableform1.$visible" style="float:right">
                                                        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="tableform1.$waiting" title=" Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-save" ng-click="NotifyClick()"> Save</button>
                                                        <input type="button" ng-disabled="tableform1.$waiting" title=" Close Edit Form Without Saving Changes" ng-click="refreshUI();tableform1.$cancel()"
                                                            class="btn btn-danger fa fa-close" value="X Cancel" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

controller code:

```
$scope.saveTable = function ()
     {
        debugger;
           if(NotifyCount!=1){
        var RoleNamechk = '';
             for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Manage_Roleser.length; i++) {
                RoleNamechk = $scope.Manage_Roleser[i].RoleName;
                 for (var j = 0; j < $scope.Manage_Roleser.length; j++) {
                var RoleName = $scope.Manage_Roleser[j].RoleName;
                if (RoleNamechk == RoleName) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (count == $scope.Manage_Roleser.length)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Manage_Roleser.length; i++) {
                var id = $scope.Manage_Roleser[i]._id;
                var rolename = $scope.Manage_Roleser[i].RoleName;
                var isactive = $scope.Manage_Roleser[i].IsActive;
                var description = $scope.Manage_Roleser[i].Description;
                if (description == "") 
                {
                    description = 'empty';
                }

                if ($scope.Manage_Roleser[i].DirtyFlag == "True") 
                {
                        $scope.LoggedinUsers = $cookieStore.get('LoggedinUser');
                       var updatedBy= $scope.LoggedinUsers;
                    $http.put('/Roleupdate/' + id + '/' + rolename + '/' + isactive + '/' + description  + '/' + updatedBy).then(function (response) {
                    refresh();
                    });

                }
                count=0;
                            }
              $notify.success('Success', 'Role is Updated Successfully');
        }
        else {
            $notify.warning('Warning', 'Role Name is Already Exists');
              count = 0;
            return '';
        }
                  }
    };
```

in ng-change I am checking dirty flag of selected index because it is updating all the row values. for that I am updating only selected($dirty) row alone. In second page it is not taking table index correctly. If I select 2nd page 3 row it will assume or taking index of the particular page. It should take index of selected row from the over all table row

```
$scope.applyHighlight = function ($data,index) {
                $scope.Manage_Roleser[index].DirtyFlag = "True";
        var dataSpan = $(event.currentTarget).closest('td');

        if (!dataSpan.hasClass("highlighted")) {
            $(dataSpan).addClass("highlighted");


        }
    }
```

Comment: post your code of html

Comment: Now, I edited my post.

Comment: I done this. In editable form I have mentioned Items per page. Based on that items page count  I am getting which page is selected and then I am checking dirty and saving the edited records.

Comment: $scope.pagination = {
            current: 1
        };

Comment: $scope.ItemsPerPageChange = function () {
           
            var e = document.getElementById("ItemsPerPageID");
            var ItemsPerPageID = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);

            $scope.ItemsPerPageCount = ItemsPerPageID;

            refresh();

        }